# Getting jquery multistep working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, multi-step

I'm trying to make a multistep form with jquery using this:

https://github.com/sheadawson/jquery.multistep

But so far I can't seem to get it working properly because it doesn't hide the other steps, can anyone provide me with an example on how to properly use this? I seem to be doing something wrong here.

Comment: what you have tried, Share your code

Comment: The example seems very straight forward.

Comment: True but my Jquery knowledge isn't that good. I'm messing around with a bit more to try and get it working but if I can't I'll post what I have. If somebody would be willing to post a simple example that would be really nice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#SignupForm").formToWizard({ submitButton: 'SaveAccount' })
        $("#makeWizard").hide();
        $("#info").fadeIn(400);
});
```

Please View a very simple example [FormToWizard](http://jsfiddle.net/A5WzZ/)